# Angular 6 : how to get specific data from Json array using Angular 6

Tags: json, angular

I have retrieved data from the JSON array in Angular 6 using GET method.
I have this JSON data as an example and I want to find employee "TEST4KRWN" in which team(s) is located.

How can I write a JSON-query using angular 6?

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "teams": [
          {
            "EMPLOYEES": [
                "TEST4KRWN",
                "TESTV6A3M"
            ],
            "TEAM_LEAD": "TEST3L671",
            "TEAM_ID": 7,
            "TEAM_NAME": "Quantum Computing"
        },
        {
            "EMPLOYEES": [
                "TESTEK9H4",
                "TEST4KRWN",
                "TESTWIOTA"
            ],
            "TEAM_LEAD": "TESTB2SEA",
            "TEAM_ID": 8,
            "TEAM_NAME": "Language"
        },

        {
            "EMPLOYEES": [
                "TESTWJJ7W"
            ],
            "TEAM_LEAD": "TESTOOARS",
            "TEAM_ID": 10,
            "TEAM_NAME": "General Services"
        },
        {
            "EMPLOYEES": [
                "TEST1S09V",
                "TEST4KRWN"
            ],
            "TEAM_LEAD": "TESTYUK99",
            "TEAM_ID": 11,
            "TEAM_NAME": "Logistik"
        },
        {
            "EMPLOYEES": [
                "TEST7QTWJ",
                "TEST4KRWN",
                "TESTMKT1K"
            ],
            "TEAM_LEAD": "TESTVYTHP",
            "TEAM_ID": 12,
            "TEAM_NAME": "R&D"
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to do that in one line:

```
 const selectedEmployee = data.teams.find(
   t => t.EMPLOYEES.find(e => e === 'TEST4KRWN')
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const selectedTeam = null;
teams.forEach((team) => {
    selectedTeam = team.EMPLOYEES.filter(function (employee, pos) {
        return employee === "TEST4KRWN";
    });
});
```

Now you could know the team from that you can access any object.

Comment: You can use `some` in place of `forEach` and return `selectedTeam`. In this way you avoid keep iterating if you have already found the selected team

Answer (score 0):

Let    `myjson` be the json data of yours :

```
 let TEAM_NAME_list =[]
    for (let item of myjson.teams){
    if(item.EMPLOYEES.includes('TEST4KRWN')){
    TEAM_NAME_list.push(item.TEAM_NAME)}
    }
```

in `TEAM_NAME_list` you will get all team(s) who have employee "TEST4KRWN"